# CSS center align in label field

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display something like this one:

[image: sample result]
* Please treat the blue line and black line as the border

In which the image description text should be **horizontal** center in the remain space, however I can't figure out what css I should apply.

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/65ky0zLg/

```
HTML:
<div>
  <img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/mjejVTJKT4ABNKq2HGlkDs36f-QvzI2hKFER098vBIgiAoZ2H-SN5QPvFaZEVDZRxfujrS6pszZ_J-_di2F57w0IFE3KAciDwGAh-9RcCA=s660" style="width: 20%; padding: 2% 2% 0% 2%" alt/>
  <label class="lbl">Martin Luther King, Jr. Day 2015</label>
</div>

CSS:
.lbl {
  font-size: larger;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to vertically align in middle  `img` and `label`, is that it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove float:left and just use verticle align with the image and that's it. Try below:

```
<div>
  <img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/mjejVTJKT4ABNKq2HGlkDs36f-QvzI2hKFER098vBIgiAoZ2H-SN5QPvFaZEVDZRxfujrS6pszZ_J-_di2F57w0IFE3KAciDwGAh-9RcCA=s660" style="width: 20%; vertical-align:middle" alt/>
  <label class="lbl">Martin Luther King, Jr. Day 2015</label>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** Above will vertically align the text. In case you want to align it horizontally, do the below:

```
<img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/mjejVTJKT4ABNKq2HGlkDs36f-QvzI2hKFER098vBIgiAoZ2H-SN5QPvFaZEVDZRxfujrS6pszZ_J-_di2F57w0IFE3KAciDwGAh-9RcCA=s660" style="width: 20%;" alt/>
<label class="lbl">Martin Luther King, Jr. Day 2015</label>
```

And use the css below:

```
.lbl {
    font-size: larger;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    left:10%;
  }
```

Working Plnkr : [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jz7FhV206HAtbnmbgWl4?p=preview)

Comment: I've update the question. In my fiddle, the description is next to the image, but I want to center in the remain space.

Comment: @Alex You want to center align it horizontally only or horizontally & vertically both ?

Comment: Horizontal only, vertical should be remain bottom as default, thanks

Comment: @Alex Please check plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/jz7FhV206HAtbnmbgWl4?p=preview and let me know if it serves your purpose.

Comment: Yes, thanks, may you help to paste it in your answer and I marked it as answer?

Comment: @Alex I have edited the post. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this by making your label `inline-block` and then top `padding` here is the code below.

```css
.lbl {
  font-size: larger;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/mjejVTJKT4ABNKq2HGlkDs36f-QvzI2hKFER098vBIgiAoZ2H-SN5QPvFaZEVDZRxfujrS6pszZ_J-_di2F57w0IFE3KAciDwGAh-9RcCA=s660" style="width: 20%; padding: 2% 2% 0% 2%" alt/>
  <label class="lbl">Martin Luther King, Jr. Day 2015</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used html for this:

```
<center>
    <label>Martin Luther King, Jr. Day 2015</label>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div >
  <img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/mjejVTJKT4ABNKq2HGlkDs36f-QvzI2hKFER098vBIgiAoZ2H-SN5QPvFaZEVDZRxfujrS6pszZ_J-_di2F57w0IFE3KAciDwGAh-9RcCA=s660" style="width: 20%; padding: 2% 2% 0% 2%;float:left" alt/>
  <label class="lbl">Martin Luther King, Jr. Day 2015</label>
</div>

<style>
.lbl {
  font-size: larger;
  float:left;
  padding:20px 0;//or use this padding: 20px 0 0 100px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thx, but I'm trying to avoid the float, otherwise I may need to redesign other component in this page

Answer (score 0):

I did it by doing this.

```
<div id="test">
  <img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/mjejVTJKT4ABNKq2HGlkDs36f-QvzI2hKFER098vBIgiAoZ2H-SN5QPvFaZEVDZRxfujrS6pszZ_J-_di2F57w0IFE3KAciDwGAh-9RcCA=s660" style="width: 20%; padding: 2% 2% 0% 2%" alt/><br>
  <label class="lbl">Martin Luther King, Jr. Day 2015</label>
</div>


#test {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: larger;
}
```

Comment: It will be better if the picture still keep on the left, but set the DIV to center will also affect the image.

Comment: So you want to have the text at the middle of the image on the right?