# Angular material horizontal Stepper spacing

Tags: css, angular, flexbox

The example spreads the tabs/labels
https://stackblitz.com/angular/mnmyvamynma?file=src/app/stepper-editable-example.ts

I would like to center the step labels and use minial gap (8px or so)

If I untick `flex: auto`, in the browser inspector - it works as expected (don't know what is the equivalent in CSS)

```
.mat-stepper-horizontal-line {
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    flex: auto;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0 -16px;
    min-width: 32px;
}
```

Tried options but didn't work: [ tried options, but last tested value is min-content]

```
::ng-deep .mat-stepper-horizontal-line {
    flex: min-content;
    min-width: 0;
}

.mat-stepper-horizontal-line {
    flex: min-content;
    min-width: 0;
    
}
```

How to do it in CSS?

Edit:
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0lMF.jpg)

Comment: Center the three labels?  This is how to do it with CSS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870309/css-center-align-in-label-field  This is how to do it with CSS and Materialize.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54728464/how-to-center-text-inputs-using-materialize-css Can you make a runnable snippet as shown there?  You're stackblitz is great, but it can change or go away over time.

Comment: please can you remove your comment, as it can make others think in the same line? Stack blitz is working absolutely fine. If I can fix, there is no meaning in asking. Note: The stackblitz is angular example, it has to be viewed in full screen, to see how wide the steppers are

Comment: We do not give reasons for downvoting. Please do not call people names and try to be polite. Downvotes have a reason when you hover over the downvote button. It says that someone didn't find your post useful. When contributing to this site you have to make sure that you add useful posts. Apparently someone didn't think your question is going to help others.

Comment: Get rid of flex auto?  8px?  Try margin auto.  Welcome to SO!

Comment: Sorry, need more details Example .mat-stepper-horizontal-line {   flex:unset; } or similar to what I posted in question as tried options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly but you can directly target the .mat-stepper-horizontal-line and use custom CSS on it. Image attached.

Let me know if you were searching for this or something else?

```
::ng-deep .mat-stepper-horizontal-line {
  flex: none !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I can accept the answer. I tried similarly (added my trial in the question), but !important is the key. I will try to get rid of the whole dotted line( and need them in the center , right now they are left aligned).